# Weak continuity of the addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed vector space. Show that vector addition and scalar multiplication are weakly continuous.
$$+:X×X \rightarrow X; +(x,y)=x+y$$
$$•:\mathbb {R}×X \rightarrow X; •(\lambda,x)=\lambda x$$
My Ideas (From Brezis book):

1. A map $f$ is weakly continuous iff 
   $\forall g \in X^*, g\circ f $ is continuous.
2. Strong to strong continuity of a linear map implies weak to weak continuity.

Can I conclude directly from 2. that since both $+$ and $•$ are strong to strong continuous, the result follows. Please I need hints on how to put the thought together

Comment: Are you sure of that point 2? I suspect that it is false. What is trivially true is that "strong to strong" implies "strong to weak". However, for linear maps you might be right.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro 2) is true, If a linear map is strong to strong continuous it is also weak to weak continuous.

Comment: Yes, of course, now I see it. The way it is posed I thought we were talking about all maps, also nonlinear ones; but for these, 2 is false. Anyway, it is not relevant since everything is linear here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, but my problem is that, is weak to weak continuity, the same as weak continuity. What is the difference. I'm confused with this because one can also have weak to strong continuity and so on.

Comment: @stackuser 'Weakly continuous linear map' is not a standard terminology in FA, so your concern is genuine. I think we have to interpret it here as weak -to - weak continuity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Gluseppe's claim is right. $f$ must be linear. In that case since $•$ is not linear one can't conclude with 2. what else can I do. please

Comment: Pretty much the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3139633/144766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak - weak continuity of $(\lambda, x) \to \lambda x$: if $(\lambda_i,x_i) \to (\lambda,x)$  then $\lambda_i\to \lambda$ and $x_i \to x$ weakly and, for any $x^{*} \in X^{*}$, we have $x^{*} (\lambda_i x_i)=\lambda_i x^{*}(x_i) \to \lambda x^{*}(x)=x^{*} (\lambda x)$.

You have to note two points: a) there is only one norm topology on $\mathbb R$; weak and strong coincide here. b) Weak topology is not metrizable in infinite dimensional spaces so we have to use nets instead of sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, from 2. you will get the weak continuity of $+$ and $•$.